# How to implement customized unfurling (preview snippets) with Branch.io quick links?

Tags: branch.io

We generate quick links in our iOS app that are supposed to point to specific content within the app. When a quick link is shared via a messaging app that supports preview snippets, we want the snippet to display custom content depending on the parameters passed when our iOS app generates a link.

For example, user wants to share an audio, the app generates a link which is then posted in a messaging app or social media. We want the preview snippet to reflect specific title/subtitle and image related to that audio.

We use a custom domain name for Branch links if that matters.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Link Preview](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#social-link-behavior) for achieving this functionality. It will enable the link to display content as a preview card in Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, iMessage, etc. This card can contain a title, description and image (that you append in the link as [OG Tags](https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#open-graph)  such as $og_title, $og_description, and $og_image_url) .